# How to use htaccess in subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

I have an htacess file in root directory as follows.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But now I have a sub domain called `fun.example.com`. I want  to rewrite files inside that sub directory. Like `fun/test.php?id=1` to `fun/test/1`. I am using get method.
How to do that? Please note that, I do not have a htaccess inside sub domain folder. I read some tutorials. But couldn't find required answer

Comment: Copy, pasta...? What is the problem?

Comment: My problem is I need to rewrite url inside subdomain.

Comment: Simply copy the `.htaccess` from the root domain to the sub domain.

Comment: I would recommend attempting URL rewriting. Just because it's a subdomain doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Is your subdomain also using wordpress?

Comment: No. Sub domain is not wordpress. I am using core PHP. I need to change my URLs as explained in question

Comment: What is document root directory of sub domain? Is it `/fun/`?

Comment: @anubhava Yes it is fun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new htaccess file in your `/fun/` directory (which I assume is the *document root* of the `fun.example.com` subdomain) with these rules:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fun\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^/]+)\.php\?id=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fun\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Place this code in `/fun/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+test\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /test/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^test/([0-9]+)/?$ /test.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Insert this rule in your root .htaccess after `RewriteBase /` line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fun\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```